# ConversionOptions does not have AudioBitRate

Tags: c#

I was making a video/audio compressor but i got stuck in this code.

```
string inputFilePath = "input.wav";
string outputFilePath = "output_compressed.aac";

    // Specify the desired audio bit rate for compression
int outputBitRate = 128000; // 128 kbps

using (var engine = new Engine())
     {
         var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = inputFilePath };
         var outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = outputFilePath };

         var options = new ConversionOptions { AudioBitRate = outputBitRate };

         engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);

         engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile, options);
      }
```

.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to:

Add:

> dotnet add package MediaFile

and:

> using MediaToolkit.Model;

The Sample Rate is an enum so your code should look as:

```
string inputFilePath = "input.wav";
string outputFilePath = "output_compressed.aac";

    // Specify the desired audio bit rate for compression
//int outputBitRate = 128000; // 128 kbps WRONG DEFINED AS ENUM using 44 k below

using (var engine = new Engine())
     {
         var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = inputFilePath };
         var outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = outputFilePath };

         var options = new ConversionOptions { AudioSampleRate = AudioSampleRate.Hz44100};

         engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);

         engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile, options);
      }
```